# How to use the non-selected value of spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to make an IoT app using firebase which makes the IoT device's pins high and low according to the value of IR sensor.
For example, if IR is ON make PIN1 HIGH (I'm able to achieve that) and when IR is LOW set PIN1 LOW (this is not working).

My spinner has only two values HIGH and LOW. I'm able to use the selected item using getSelectedItem(). But want to access the non-selected item as well.

```
          myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.

                    if(StringValue.length()>0 && link2.length()>0) {

                       try{ status = dataSnapshot.child("Analog").getValue().toString();}
                       catch (NullPointerException ignored){

                       }
                        if(status==null){
                            TextView text4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                            text4.setText(" Error: Wrong ID. ");
                            // Toast...
                            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 540);
                            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setView(layout);
                            toast.show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else{ analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);
                        pin.setText(status);


                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
                        if (analogvalue >= value) {


                            Firebase fireChild = fire2.child( "Pin1");
                            fireChild.setValue(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            Firebase fireChild1 = fire2.child( "Pin2");
                            fireChild1.setValue(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        }

//this is not working:
                        if(analogvalue < value){

                            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                            else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                            if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                            else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}

                        }
```

Does anyone know how to use the non-selected value of spinner?[image: This is how my screen looks like]

Comment: What do you mean "non-selected value"? You might have set any adapter to the spinner which has all of your values.

Comment: @ss007 In my spinner there are only two values. I want to know how to access both selected and non-selected values.

Comment: well, you might have somewhere stored all your spinner values. How are you setting spinner values, anyway?

Comment: @ss007 I have initialize the spinner with 2 values in the Activity file. Can you tell me any function or way to access them?